# Allow multiple values issue on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to select multiple values parameter on SSRS.
I used depended dropdown parameter.
For example my type parameter data set is:

```
    select '<All>' 'TYPE'
union
    SELECT DISTINCT STR_TYPE   'TYPE'
        FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[LFP_MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID
```

my class parameter's dataset code is: 
(class parameter dropdown list depends on type parameter value)

```
    select '<All>' 'CLASS'
union
    SELECT DISTINCT STR_CLASS 'CLASS'
    FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[LFP_MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID 
    WHERE (@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>' OR  M.STR_TYPE in (@MATERIAL_TYPE))
```

Normally I can show my report like this:

[image]

When I select the "allow multiple values" for class parameter and If I select two values for class, I face to below error:

[image]

How should I pass this error?
Could you help me about this issue?

Thanks:)

Comment: You need to split your multi select string. At the moment it's coming back as 'a,b,c,d' as apposed to 'a','b','c','d'. Split into a table then join it onto the query. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2009/04/28/sqlclr-string-splitting-part-2-even-faster-even-more-scalable.aspx

Comment: How can I split my select string for sql? could you help me?

Comment: Sorry wrong link . https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: Hello, I can use multiple value now:) Thanks for your help.