# select all doesn't work correctly on SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created report on SSRS. Report parameter allow multiple values.
When I select "allow multiple values" properties, parameter dropdown show me "select all" but when I choose "select all" report result doesn't correctly.

And I created for my report all selection. when I select "all" my report result show correctly.

Do you know Could I remove "select all" when I use "allow multiple values"?
Or How can I fix this problem?

These are my parameters:
I have got "select all" and "all" in my dropdown:
[image]

When I choose "all" for my all parameter my report result will be true:
[image]

When I choose "select all" for my all parameter my report result will be wrong:
[image]

---

## Scripts

This is my main script:
NOTE: SplitString is my function which split parameter values

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Material_Lot_Properties_Report]
    
    @MATERIAL_TYPE VARCHAR(50)
    ,@MATERIAL_CLASS VARCHAR(50)
    , @MATERIAL VARCHAR(50)
    ,@PROPERTYID VARCHAR(50)
    ,@PVALUE VARCHAR(50)
    
    AS
    
    --*/
    
    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TYPIES AS TABLE
        (
            TYPE VARCHAR(10)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @TYPIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_TYPE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @TYPIES
    
    
    DECLARE @CLASSES AS TABLE
        (
            CLASS VARCHAR(10)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @CLASSES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_CLASS,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @CLASSES
    
    
    
    DECLARE @MATERIALS AS TABLE
        (
            MATERIAL VARCHAR(10)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @MATERIALS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @MATERIALS
    
    
    DECLARE @PROPERTIES AS TABLE
        (
            PROPERTY VARCHAR(50)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @PROPERTIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@PROPERTYID,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @PROPERTIES
    
    
    
    
    DECLARE @VALUES AS TABLE
        (
            VALUE VARCHAR(50)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @VALUES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@PVALUE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @VALUES
    
    
    
    
    SELECT 
            M.STR_TYPE      [TYPE],
            M.STR_CLASS     [CLASS],
            DEFID,
            DEFNAME,
            L.LOTID,
            PROPERTYID,
            P.PVALUE
    FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[LFP_MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID
        WHERE P.PValue IS NOT NULL
            AND (@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>' OR  M.STR_TYPE IN (SELECT * FROM @TYPIES))
            AND (@MATERIAL_CLASS= '<All>' OR  M.STR_CLASS IN (SELECT * FROM @CLASSES))
            AND (@MATERIAL= '<All>' OR M.STR_MATERIAL_ID IN (SELECT * FROM @MATERIALS))
            AND (@PROPERTYID= '<All>' OR PropertyID IN (SELECT * FROM @PROPERTIES))
            AND (@PVALUE = '<All>' OR PVALUE IN (SELECT * FROM @VALUES))
    
    
    END
```

this is my split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1
       
        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

And this is my class parameter script:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Material_Lot_Properties_Report_for_Class_Parameter]
    
    @MATERIAL_TYPE VARCHAR(50)
    
    
    AS
    
    --*/
    
    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON
    
    
    
    
    DECLARE @TYPIES AS TABLE
        (
            TYPE VARCHAR(10)
        )
    
    INSERT INTO @TYPIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_TYPE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @TYPIES
    
        SELECT '<All>' 'CLASS'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT M.STR_CLASS     CLASS
    FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID
        WHERE P.PValue IS NOT NULL
        AND (@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>' OR  M.STR_TYPE IN (SELECT * FROM @TYPIES))
    
    
    END
```

Comment: When using multi selects you can't remove the "Select All" option. As a rule of thumb when using multi selects it's best to split the string that result from the multi select param into a table and join it to your source proc. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: @Snowlockk  Why would you advise splitting the string as a rule of thumb?  I would suggest that this is only necessary if your parameter list is *huge* and would bog down an `in()` statement, but at that point you are probably better of simply changing your entire approach...

Comment: @iamdave read my comment below

Comment: You can let the multiselect work for you, you don't need a split function. In your WHERE clause your filter could look like  WHERE ( '<All>' IN (@MATERIAL_TYPE) OR M.STR_TYPE IN (@MATERIAL_TYPE))

Answer (score 1):

## As you have not included your dataset script this is about as far as I can go without romping off into the world of probably pointless speculation, update your answer to include this and you will get a more targeted response

---

It looks like either your report parameters were once a single valued parameter in which an `<All>` option was manually added or whoever built this reports was not aware of how multi value parameters work in SSRS.

If you set your parameter as multi valued, the `(Select All)` option is added by SSRS automatically and literally just ticks every box.  Every option that is ticked is passed through to your query as a value that can be used in an `in()` statement as follows:

```
select Col1
      ,Col2
from Table
where Col2 in(@SSRSParameter)
```

---

It looks like your query is actually set up to handle single values or a literal '' in a similar way to this:

```
select Col1
      ,Col2
from Table
where Col2 = @SSRSParameter
   or @SSRSParameter = '<All>'
```

Which will give you unexpected behaviour if you are now passing your values from a multi valued parameter.

Comment: With the IN clause, when the parameter returned is a string wouldn't it effectively be 'a,b,c,d' instead of 'a','b','c','d'. IN shouldn't work for this. you would need to split the string on the commas.

Comment: @Snowlockk  This is definitely how it works.  Kindly try this out for yourself before telling me it is wrong.

Comment: CREATE Table Test (Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO Test 
SELECT 1,'a'

DECLARE @SSRSParameter VARCHAR(10) = 'a,b,c,d'


select Col1
      ,Col2
from Test
where Col2 in(@SSRSParameter)

DROP TABLE Test

Comment: @Snowlockk  Well that isn't really trying this out is it?  Of course that won't work.  SSRS is smarter than you and passes the string values to the `in()` statement without issue.  *Actually* try this out for yourself within SSRS.

Comment: How do you know OP isn't using source procs?

Comment: @Snowlockk  Now that is a different issue around how OP is using SSRS and not something we can comment on.  Shared Datasets exist for a reason and offer many solutions to problems with both embedded datasets and source sprocs.

Comment: I'm giving my comments like this as OP asked a question last week about multi selects where she used IN and was getting errors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432133/allow-multiple-values-issue-on-ssrs

Comment: @Snowlockk  That error is because the OP is using both `@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>'` as well as `M.STR_TYPE in (@MATERIAL_TYPE)` in the `where` clause.  I have just tested this and also error on report execution where more than one parameter value is selected.

Comment: I am using to function which is split parameter for all parameter and now I can select one more than values for parameter. and tried remove "all" and when I choose "select all" again I face same issue. "select all" didn't work correctly. and right I have a lot of values in my dropdown. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: @Aylin  As I stated at the top of my answer, I can't offer you any more help without your dataset script.  Are you using a stored procedure or SQL Script?  What is the script?

Comment: I wrote my scripts. other parameter scripts like class parameter script

Comment: @Aylin  Remove the `<All>` option and any reference to it in your scripts.  When you tick the built in `(Select All)` option, all SSRS is doing is automatically ticking every single parameter option and then passing them all to your query in the same way as if you only ticked a couple.  You do not need to have a manually created `<All>` option.

Comment: @Aylin  You will also get better performance on your split function using either [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) method or [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/) method instead of a while loop.

Comment: @iamdave I remove "All" but still "select all " doesn't work correctly. select all put tick for all value in dropdown but it just show 4 or 5 value in the report result. how can I handle this problem?

Comment: @Aylin  That will be because there is a problem in your query logic.  Having a filter the either isn't applied because you selected an `<All>` value is not the same as selecting all available values.  If you have any records with a type that is not included in your parameter list it will be excluded from your report when passing all options to your query.

Comment: Yes you are right I can use "select all" correctly. problem was my query logic and parameter field. I am using varchar(max) and now it is working. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

This is my main script:
NOTE: SplitString is my function which split parameter values

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Material_Lot_Properties_Report]

    @MATERIAL_TYPE VARCHAR(50)
    ,@MATERIAL_CLASS VARCHAR(50)
    , @MATERIAL VARCHAR(50)
    ,@PROPERTYID VARCHAR(50)
    ,@PVALUE VARCHAR(50)

    AS

    --*/

    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @TYPIES AS TABLE
        (
            TYPE VARCHAR(10)
        )

    INSERT INTO @TYPIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_TYPE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @TYPIES


    DECLARE @CLASSES AS TABLE
        (
            CLASS VARCHAR(10)
        )

    INSERT INTO @CLASSES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_CLASS,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @CLASSES



    DECLARE @MATERIALS AS TABLE
        (
            MATERIAL VARCHAR(10)
        )

    INSERT INTO @MATERIALS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @MATERIALS


    DECLARE @PROPERTIES AS TABLE
        (
            PROPERTY VARCHAR(50)
        )

    INSERT INTO @PROPERTIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@PROPERTYID,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @PROPERTIES




    DECLARE @VALUES AS TABLE
        (
            VALUE VARCHAR(50)
        )

    INSERT INTO @VALUES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@PVALUE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @VALUES




    SELECT 
            M.STR_TYPE      [TYPE],
            M.STR_CLASS     [CLASS],
            DEFID,
            DEFNAME,
            L.LOTID,
            PROPERTYID,
            P.PVALUE
    FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[LFP_MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID
        WHERE P.PValue IS NOT NULL
            AND (@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>' OR  M.STR_TYPE IN (SELECT * FROM @TYPIES))
            AND (@MATERIAL_CLASS= '<All>' OR  M.STR_CLASS IN (SELECT * FROM @CLASSES))
            AND (@MATERIAL= '<All>' OR M.STR_MATERIAL_ID IN (SELECT * FROM @MATERIALS))
            AND (@PROPERTYID= '<All>' OR PropertyID IN (SELECT * FROM @PROPERTIES))
            AND (@PVALUE = '<All>' OR PVALUE IN (SELECT * FROM @VALUES))


    END
```

this is my split function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

And this is my class parameter script:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Material_Lot_Properties_Report_for_Class_Parameter]

    @MATERIAL_TYPE VARCHAR(50)


    AS

    --*/

    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON




    DECLARE @TYPIES AS TABLE
        (
            TYPE VARCHAR(10)
        )

    INSERT INTO @TYPIES 
    SELECT * 
    FROM [dbo].[SplitString] (@MATERIAL_TYPE,',')
    --SELECT * FROM @TYPIES

        SELECT '<All>' 'CLASS'
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT M.STR_CLASS     CLASS
    FROM [DBO].[MMWLOTS] L
        JOIN  [DBO].[MMWLOTPRPVALS]  P
    ON P.LOTPK=L.LOTPK
        JOIN [DBO].[MATERIALS] M
    ON M.STR_MATERIAL_ID=L.DEFID
        WHERE P.PValue IS NOT NULL
        AND (@MATERIAL_TYPE= '<All>' OR  M.STR_TYPE IN (SELECT * FROM @TYPIES))


    END
```